# Why "Windows XP won't install" instead of "Windows XP don't install"?

Tags: plural-forms, auxiliary-verbs

OK. In my native language usage (non English) using *don't* looks better than *won't*. But still I'm seeing lot of *won't* instead of *don't*. So is *don't* unacceptable in this situation?

Reference link: [Tom's Hardware: Windows XP won't install (copy error)](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/237352-45-windows-install-copy-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Don't* is a contraction of *do not*, and since Windows XP is not a plural, you actually need to use *does not* or *doesn't* instead:

> Why doesn't Windows XP install?

So in answer to your question, *Is 'don't' unacceptable in this situation*, the answer is *yes*. You must either use *won't* or *doesn't*.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is correct, but many people use *don't* for *doesn't* in informal contexts, particularly if they're either *actually* uneducated, or facetiously imitating uneducated speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's true. There's also the African American vernacular which uses it frequently (e.g. "This don't make no sense", "That don't mean a thing" etc), although for most spoken and written English, particularly for English learners outside of quoted vernacular speech, "doesn't" should still be preferred in this context.

Comment: I generally say “Window XP will not install.” Is this correct?

Comment: @EnglishLearner Yes, that is correct.